# Using dplyr tools for PostgreSQL over SSL

Tags: r, postgresql, ssl, dplyr, amazon-redshift

I've been using dplyr's SQL backend for certain databases. But I can't get it to work with one that uses SSL authentication.

I keep getting this error:

> RS-DBI driver: (could not connect [username]@[host] on dbname "[dbname]")

I tried adapting the top-voted question here:

[Connect to Redshift via SSL using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482913/connect-to-redshift-via-ssl-using-r/30987389#30987389)

By passing the SSL parameters via dbname. But got the same error as above.

The top answer here:

[Can not connect PostgreSQL(over SSL) with RPostgresql on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942118/can-not-connect-postgresqlover-ssl-with-rpostgresql-on-windows)

Worked for me, but it only lets me pass SQL commands via R, not to write dplyr commands that are translated to SQL.

Anyone else encounter this and have a fix?

Comment: You could try to open an ssh tunnel to the postgres instance e.g. via putty and use portforwarding. That way you would only connect to localhost:2345 and you are connected via ssl. (assumg 2345 is the port you forward to remote.host:port-of-postgres)